# remove code from angular builds

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, preprocessor

I'm wondering how I could increase productivity in angular2+ development.
At the moment, I have for instance, a registration form.
This registration form model is populated with real data during development, and removed by hand just before building.

Isn't there a way to tell the 'compiler' hey if you compile in prod mode, just ignore this! some sort of preprocessor code like this pseudocode:

```
let rdata = {id:null, pass:null}
@@ignoreprod_start
  rdata.id = 2766;
  rdata.pass = "@(F-§44$A_NG%%p";
@@ignoreprod_end
```

Comment: Hi! Did you figure this out? I'm looking for the exact same thing - something like **gulp-remove-code** but with the angular cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in Angular 4 and 5, there we have angular-cli.json and this file has apps.environments property, where you can specify to compiler accordingly. attaching my file just for reference, this is just a pointer not a complete answer, you need to see for yourself what you can do, however ask me for any clarification, this files environment.prod.ts and environment.ts are defined in environment folder, it will depend on which version of angular you are using

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "dncockpit"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but this is clearly the way to go when handling variables only to be used locally. I just accepted your answer